# Alkali Metal Rosinates Solubility in Acetone

Tags: solubility

In violin finishing technology alkali metal Rosinates are used in varnish synthesis. Usually this alkali metal Rosinates are soluble in Turpentine. I also know that Copper, Zinc Rosinates are soluble in Diethyl ether. However, beside Turpentine I want to know if this alkali metal Rosinates ($\ce{K,\ Na,\ NH4+}$ - Rosinates) are soluble in Acetone especially or in Diethyl Ether or in any other  VOC’s?

Comment: Would water-solvent mixtures be acceptable?  Are you still interested in this?

Comment: water based ones are worth a try